# How to Finish the Previous Activity and Start the New Activity from a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcastreceiver

In my code I am having a Broadcast Receiver for incoming SMS.If SMS is from a Specific sender I am changing my current Activity and start a new Activity.
But the Issue is even if I change the Activity when I press on back button, It takes me to the previous activity.How to stop taking me to the previous activity?

Here is my code

```
                if (message.startsWith("Welcome")) {
                    String[] splitArray = message.split(" "); // splits the string message from the spaces contains in it
                    String pin = splitArray[7]; // grab the 7th index since it contains the PIN
                    //Log.d("PINRead:", pin);
                    pin = pin.replace(".", "");
                    //Log.e("DotRemoved",pin);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PIN.edit();
                    editor.putString("PIN", pin);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, PINActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    i.putExtra("PIN", pin); // Pass the pin to next Activity
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
```

Comment: add finish(); before startActivity()

Comment: Try to add this i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); with your Intent.

Comment: @PreetikaKaur OP is starting his `Activity` from a BroadcastReceiver`. You can't call `finish()` from a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @ajantha adding `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` would clear the stack back to the previous instance of `PINActivity`. I'm assuming that there isn't an active instance of `PINActivity` in the stack, so this solution wouldn't work.